# Understanding Dates in Shared With Details Column

Tags: sharepoint-online, office-365

I'm looking into using the Shared With Details column for something and I don't understand some of the values. I see the user and then a DateTime value, which would be amazing if it referred to the date of the share, but it's just a long string of numbers that does not seem to reflect any date. 
For ex this is what it looks like when I shared a document today:

{"i:0#.f|membership|firstname.lastname@domain.org":{"DateTime":"/Date(1557740213028)/","LoginName":"person.who.shared@domain.org"}}

Any clarity on the DateTime meaning/format?

Answer (score 0):

Since `Date` in JavaScript has no representation in `JSON`, multiple formats exists to represent a `Date` when using `JSON`. The `Date(xxx)`-Version is Microsoft special...

If you want to use the value in **JavaScript**, simply extract the numbers and initialize a `Date` using the number. From the example above:

```
var d = new Date();
d.setTime(1557740213028);
```

will give you the `Date` in question.
See also https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1016847/converting-net-datetime-to-json and https://stackoverflow.com/questions/206384/how-do-i-format-a-microsoft-json-date

*However*, to parse the value from a **[Flow](https://flow.microsoft.com/)** - this is not so trivial.

1. I started out by defining a "demo" json:
   [image: demo-json]
2. define a variable of type `object` to contain the parsed json
   [image: object]
3. define a variable of type `string` to contain the date-string
   [image: date-string]
4. define a variable of type `integer` to contain the length of the numers in the date-string
   [image: len of numbers]
   the value of the expression is `sub(length(variables('extractedProperty')), 8)` - the 8 is due to the 6 charaters in front (`/Date(`) plus the last two (`)/`).
5. define a variable of type `integer` to contain the value of the number (i.e. the milliseconds since Jan. 1st 1970)
   [image: parsed numbers]
   the value of the expression is `int(substring(variables('extractedProperty'), 6, variables('lenOfNumbers')))`
6. define a variable of type `string` to hold the result
   [image: the result] 
   the value of the expression is `addSeconds('1970-01-01T00:00:00Z', div(variables('onlyTheNumber'),1000), 'o')`.

The result is a `string` that can be used as a `timestamp` in following actions. Notice that it is not exact, since the number in the json is milliseconds and flow accepts only full seconds. (Taking your example from above, the result will be off by 28 milliseconds...)

Comment: Thanks so much Nils, I've never used JSON, and I'm trying to use this date value in a Flow. I managed to use a couple Compose actions to get just the date string, but I'm not sure how to use your suggestion above in a Parse JSON action. Could you give me the whole code?

Comment: I added a rough idea on how to do this in flow - there is probably a much better way...

Comment: If you feel the answer helped, feel free to mark it as such.